# Doctrine DQL: how to get expression to inversed side

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I wish to fetch an entity where the inversed association does not exist (on a 1:1 association)

I get the error:

> A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Use an
>     explicit join instead.

Query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
                SELECT DISTINCT(p.date)
                FROM MainBundle:Price p
                WHERE p.emaPrice IS NULL
                ORDER BY p.date ASC
            ")
            ->setMaxResults(1);
        $date = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

I understand the error, but I'm really stuck on fixing it. I've read I should add an explicit JOIN, but I've added it and still no luck.

**EDIT**
query with join:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
        SELECT DISTINCT(p.date)
        FROM MainBundle:Price p
        JOIN MomentumBundle:EmaPrice ep
        WITH ep.id = p.emaPrice
        WHERE p.emaPrice IS NULL
        ORDER BY p.date ASC
    ")
    ->setMaxResults(1);
$date = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: How does your query look like with the join ?

Comment: @Flip added join query

Comment: Can you get it to work in native SQL ?

Comment: I'm confused by your query. You join on `ep.id = p.emaPrice` but then have `WHERE p.emaPrice IS NULL`. That will never match anything even if the query worked.

Comment: in that case a LEFT JOIN is needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to thank @Flip and @lifo for their great support in helping me resolve this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
        SELECT DISTINCT(p.date)
        FROM MainBundle:Price p
        LEFT JOIN MomentumBundle:EmaPrice ep
        WITH ep.price = p.id
        WHERE ep IS NULL
        ORDER BY p.date ASC
    ")
    ->setMaxResults(1);
$date = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```